# Read JSON with Angular, undefined service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to read a JSON data from a file using angular factory and service. But Angular can't see my defined service. Here is my factory:

```
//jsonService.js
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
    alert($resource)
    return $resource('example.json',{}, {
        getData: {method:'GET', isArray: false}
    });
});
```

And my controller:

```
//app.js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'myApp.view1',
'myApp.view2',
'myApp.version',
'jsonService'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]).
controller('mainController', ['JsonService', function($scope, JsonService){
    JsonService.getData(function(data) {
      console.log("Test");
      $scope.length = data.length;
  })}]);
```

And I get:

> "Error: JsonService is undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're injecting `'JsonService'` as the first parameter of your function, but you are using the JsonService as the 2nd parameter of your function.

Should be `['JsonService', '$scope', function($scope, JsonService){` or if `$scope` not needed then `['JsonService', function(JsonService){`

Answer (score 1):

This line in app.js should look like

`controller('mainController', ['$scope','JsonService', function($scope, JsonService){`